# Ubuntu 20.04 install on new Lenovo Ideapad 5 AMD - No sreen rotation option, Tablet mode dyfunctional and no fingerprint option

Tags: fingerprint-reader, amd-ryzen, display-rotation

Just bought a new a Lenovo Ideapad 5 with AMD Ryzen 4500. Dual booting Ubuntu and Windows 10. The following features are missing despite following the steps in Ubuntu Wiki Documentation. Any solutions to the following problems?:

1. Screen rotation is not activated even when I enter display settings and try to adjust manually. Have also installed ARandR and cannot change orientation. System Menu also does not have a screen rotation icon or option. Anyway to activate this feature on my system?
2. Tablet mode functionality is limited - Mainly I cannot move the cursor with my finger and screen continues to look like it is in computer mode. No changes in appearance are apparent.
3. Computer has fingerprint reader that works with Windows. Ubuntu docs say I should be able to activate in my user settings with admin credentials. I am operating with those credentials and see no option for using fingerprint reader after unlocking the settings. Anyway to do this?

Is my issue a lack of support for the AMD drivers?

Answer (score 1):

For all AMD Renoir as your Ryzen 4500 **you need kernel >=5.8**

If you try :

```
$ glxinfo | egrep "(OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer|OpenGL version)"
```

You will get an answer with `OpenGL vendor string: VMware`. This is wrong.

Follow this to install the last kernel >= 5.8

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mainline
```

In the menu go to **Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer** and install a 5.8 kernel

After reboot you will get something with AMD Renoir from glxinfo :

```
$  glxinfo | egrep "(OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer|OpenGL version)"
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RENOIR (DRM 3.38.0, 5.8.8-050808-generic, LLVM 10.0.0)
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
```

You will perhaps need other steep to get all work fine but this is the first one.